# Can someone explain the isomorphism $\frac{V[[h]]}{h^nV[[h]]}\cong V \otimes \frac{\mathbb{C}[h]}{h^n\mathbb{C}[h]}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $V$ be a complex vector space, $V[[h]]$ the ring of former power series over $V$, $\mathbb{C}[h]$ the complex polynomial ring over $h$. Can somebody explain the isomorphism: $$\frac{V[[h]]}{h^nV[[h]]}\cong V \otimes \frac{\mathbb{C}[h]}{h^n\mathbb{C}[h]}$$

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? You would seem active enough to know what a good question looks like... Both quotients kill everything of degree $n$ or bigger so they're just polynomials of degree at most $n-1$ with coefficients in $V$.

Comment: What happens when you tensor the short exact sequence
$$0\to h^n\Bbb{C}[[h]]\to\Bbb{C}[[h]]\to\Bbb{C}[[h]]/\langle h^n\rangle\to0$$ with $V$?

Comment: So $V$ is a flat $\mathbb{C}$ module, so the sequence will split, and boom, I see, very nice. Thanks both of you!!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Actually I don't see.. I see that the sequence splits, but I don't see where $V[[h]]$ comes into play

Comment: Flatness says that it remains exact, not that it splits. Write the left two components in a different way.

Comment: Got it!! Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The isomorphism

$$ V[[h]]/h^n V[[h]] \cong V[h]/h^nV[h] $$

is given by

$$ v_1 + v_2 h + \dots + v_{n-1} h^{n-1} + h^n V[[h]] \longmapsto v_1 + v_2 h + \dots + v_{n-1} h^{n-1} + h^n V[h].$$

And clearly $ V[h]/h^nV[h] \cong V\otimes_k k[h]/h^n k[h]$.

Note: I don't think that the suggested in the comments approach through exact sequences will work because $V \otimes_k k[[h]]$ is not isomorphic to $V[[h]]$, when $V$ is infinite dimensional.